# Random number in Lua script Load Impact

Tags: random, lua, httprequest

I'm trying to create a random number generator in Lua. I found out that I can just use `math.random(1,100)` to randomize a number between 1 and 100 and that should be sufficient.

But I don't really understand how to use the randomize number as variables in the script.

Tried this but of course it didn't work.

```
$randomCorr = math.random(1,100);

http.request_batch({
    {"POST", "https://store.thestore.com/priceAndOrder/selectProduct", headers={["Content-Type"]="application/json;charset=UTF-8"}, data="{\"ChoosenPhoneModelId\":4,\"PricePlanId\":\"phone\",\"CorrelationId\":\"$randomCorr\",\"DeliveryTime\":\"1 vecka\",\"$$hashKey\":\"006\"},\"ChoosenAmortization\":{\"AmortizationLength\":0,\"ChoosenDataPackage\":{\"Description\":\"6 GB\",\"PricePerMountInKr\":245,\"DataAmountInGb\":6,\"$$hashKey\":\"00W\"},\"ChoosenPriceplan\":{\"IsPostpaid\":true,\"Title\":\"Fastpris\",\"Description\":\"Fasta kostnader till fast pris\",\"MonthlyAmount\":0,\"AvailiableDataPackages\":null,\"SubscriptionBinding\":0,\"$$hashKey\":\"00K\"}}", auto_decompress=true},
    {"GET", "https://store.thestore.com/api/checkout/getproduct?correlationId=$randomCorr", auto_decompress=true},
    })
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In **Lua**, you can not start a variable name with `$`. This is where your main issue is at. Once the `$` is removed from your code, we can easily see how to refer to variables in Lua.

```
randomCorr = math.random(100)
print("The random number:", randomCorr)
randomCorr = math.random(100)
print("New Random Number:", randomCorr)
```

Also, concatenation does not work the way you are implying it into your Http array. You have to concatenate the value in using `..` in Lua

Take a look at the following example:

```
ran = math.random(100)
data = "{\""..ran.."\"}"
print(data)
--{"14"}
```

The same logic can be implied into your code:

```
data="{\"ChoosenPhoneModelId\":4,\"PricePlanId\":\"phone\",\"CorrelationId\":\""..randomCorr.."\",\"DeliveryTime\":\"1 vecka\",\"$$hashKey\":\"006\"},\"ChoosenAmortization\":{\"AmortizationLength\":0,\"ChoosenDataPackage\":{\"Description\":\"6 GB\",\"PricePerMountInKr\":245,\"DataAmountInGb\":6,\"$$hashKey\":\"00W\"},\"ChoosenPriceplan\":{\"IsPostpaid\":true,\"Title\":\"Fastpris\",\"Description\":\"Fasta kostnader till fast pris\",\"MonthlyAmount\":0,\"AvailiableDataPackages\":null,\"SubscriptionBinding\":0,\"$$hashKey\":\"00K\"}}"
```

Or you can format the value in using one of the methods provided by the string library

Take a look at the following example:

```
ran = math.random(100)
data = "{%q}"
print(string.format(data,ran))
--{"59"}
```

The `%q` specifier will take whatever you put as input, and safely surround it with quotations

The same logic can be applied to your Http Data.

Comment: Thank you so much. have banking my head over this :)
working like a charm now. thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a corrected version of the code snippet:

```
local randomCorr = math.random(1,100)

http.request_batch({
{"POST", "https://store.thestore.com/priceAndOrder/selectProduct", headers={["Content-Type"]="application/json;charset=UTF-8"}, data="{\"ChoosenPhoneModelId\":4,\"PricePlanId\":\"phone\",\"CorrelationId\":\"" .. randomCorr .. "\",\"DeliveryTime\":\"1 vecka\",\"$$hashKey\":\"006\"},\"ChoosenAmortization\":{\"AmortizationLength\":0,\"ChoosenDataPackage\":{\"Description\":\"6 GB\",\"PricePerMountInKr\":245,\"DataAmountInGb\":6,\"$$hashKey\":\"00W\"},\"ChoosenPriceplan\":{\"IsPostpaid\":true,\"Title\":\"Fastpris\",\"Description\":\"Fasta kostnader till fast pris\",\"MonthlyAmount\":0,\"AvailiableDataPackages\":null,\"SubscriptionBinding\":0,\"$$hashKey\":\"00K\"}}", auto_decompress=true},
{"GET", "https://store.thestore.com/api/checkout/getproduct?correlationId=" .. randomCorr, auto_decompress=true},
})
```

There is something called $$hashKey also, in the quoted string. Not sure if that is supposed to be referencing a variable or not. If it is, it also needs to be concatenated into the resulting string, using the .. operator (just like with the randomCorr variable).